# imacros stuggling

Tags: firefox, scripting, imacros

```
//declaring the macro
 var macroIronMaiden;

  macroIronMaiden ="CODE:";
 macroIronMaiden +="VERSION BUILD=7500718 RECORDER=FX"+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO"+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
 macroIronMaiden +="SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 15"+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="TAB T=1"+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS"+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=OK CONTENT="+"\n";
macroIronMaiden +="URL GOTO=http://google.com/search=ironmaiden/"+"\n";
 macroIronMaiden +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:Leyton EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";
```

////////THIS ISNT WORKING, I WANT IT TO EXTRACT ANY ""LEYTON"" TEXT ON  PAGE/////////////////////////

```
var macroWait;

macroWait ="CODE:";
macroWait +="WAIT SECONDS=600";    
////////Beginning///////


 //this loop will search 10 times. Change number 10 for more times

for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
 {

iimPlay(macroIronMaiden)

var extract=iimGetLastExtract();

if(extract.toLowerCase()=="eddy")
```

/////////////////////////////the word leyton on the     search results page is spelled ""Leyton". how can i change this so its not just lowercase letters////////////////////////////////

```
  {

//go to yahoo.ca
}
 else
{

    iimDisplay("Waiting for 10 minutes")
  iimPlay(macroWait)
  //////////go back to top and search again.
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to world of problems with iMacros. This could be the problem.

```
macroIronMaiden +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:Leyton EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";
```

Check is the type on the page set the right way. It could be different then P. Could be DIV,SPAN or something else.

If you want to change the text in JavaScript to lower case use.

```
text=text.toLowerCase();
```

and set it to iMacros with iimSet command. Visit [this page too](http://wiki.imacros.net/Main_Page)

Comment: can I just say if(extract=="Leyton") do this and forget about if(extract.toLowerCase()=="Leyton")

Comment: * could I just say if iimGetLastExtract()==Leyton do this?? and take out var extract=iimGetLastExtract();

if(extract.toLowerCase()=="Leyton")

Comment: and if I need to check if text is more than one word do I do this....if(extract.toLowerCase()=="iron<SP>maiden<SP>are<SP>from<SP>england") or just if(extract.toLowerCase()=="iron maiden are from england")?? thanks!!!!!

Comment: 1. Yes that is precise way to do it.
2. No.
3. When text is extracted there is no <SP> in it. Only when you set the text in macro you use <SP> for spaces.

Comment: IceD you're a lifesaver! and what if I extract a whole header that's super long to type out. for example what if i wanted to check if this was on the page were currently on "Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Learn more…"??

Comment: Will i have to copy it all in if(extract.toLowercase()=="Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Learn more…")

Comment: Now that is something like the keyword recognition? That much text is too much for comparing since if 1 letter is different then the function will return false. You can try to compare it to more words like a set of keywords. But still that is too much work and results are not 100% accurate. Think of an easier approach. Couple of days ago I tried to scrape all links from HTML code on page. I struggled with JS for a LOT. Later I just used iMAcros TAG command to do the job. MUCH MUCH easier. Find me on chat when you get rep.